# Converting WAV File to Byte Array Slows Down Audio

Tags: c#, .net, audio, arrays

when I convert a WAV file to a byte array the file slows down. As in I am converting a song and the song's speed drops drastically.

This is the line of code I am using to convert the WAV file to a byte array:

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\Documents\Song.wav");
```

EDIT:

To play the audio I am using Discord.Net API to play the audio via voice chat.

Here is the line of code I am using to play the audio:

```
c.GetVoiceClient(e.Server).SendVoicePCM(bytes, bytes.Length);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "the file slows down"? Do you play it with another program?

Comment: I am using the Discord.Net api to play youtube videos via voice chat, and to play the song the audio needs to be in a byte array, but when the song is played it is audibly slowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most probable explanation is that the wav file has a higher sampling rate and plays back faster than the playback code. The first 44 bytes of the wave file don't actually contain any audio data at all but instead contain a WAV header that has within the sample rate of the recorded audio. You need to dig that out rather than trying to play it and pass the information along to Discord.Net. I don't know that API so you'll need to figure that part out on your own.